# How to use terraform to add an alarm to the load balancer created by Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add an alarm that got triggered when there are too many 5xx errors in the application load balancer created by an Elastic Beanstalk environment.

The EB environment is created by a terraform script. I can only know the name of the load balancer after the resource [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html) is created by terraform.

[This page](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/elastic-beanstalk-environment/aws/0.11.0?tab=outputs) says that [elastic-beanstalk-environment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html) has an output which is called `elb_load_balancers`. I think that I probably can use this output to create a [aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_metric_alarm.html) resource.

The following terraform script is what I have done now. It's not working

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm_5xx" {
  alarm_name          = "EB 5XX Alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "10"

  dimensions = {
    # How can I put the name of the dynamically generated load balancer here?
    LoadBalancer = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my_eb_environment_name.elb_load_balancers}" # This line doesn't work
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors number of 5xx erros in the application load balancer"
}
```

The above script generates the following error when I run `terraform apply -target=aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_5xx`:

```
* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_5xx: Resource 'aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my_eb_environment_name' does not have attribute 'elb_load_balancers' for variable 'aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my_eb_environment_name.elb_load_balancers'
```

I've also tried

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm_5xx" {
  alarm_name          = "EB 5XX Alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "10"

  dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.RightestCARE-Api-Prod-Terraform.load_balancers}" # This line doesn't work
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors number of 5xx erros in the application load balancer"
}
```

But this generates the error below:

`* aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm.alarm_5xx: dimensions (LoadBalancerName): '' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'`

Comment: The output from the `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment` resource is just [`load_balancers`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html#load_balancers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to `ydaetskcoR`'s comment. I've found that the following script works.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm_5xx" {
  alarm_name          = "EB 5XX Alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "10"

  dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.my_eb_environment_name.load_balancers[0]}" 
  }

  alarm_description = "This metric monitors number of 5xx erros in the application load balancer"
}
```

Terraform's [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html#load_balancers) says that it has a [load_balancers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html#load_balancers) attribute exported.

And because I only have 1 load balancer inside an EB environment, I can use `load_balancers[0]` to get the only load balancer.

Comment: Your answer is wrong because you've used `elb_load_balancers` again instead of `load_balancers` as the output attribute.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I changed `elb_load_balancers` to `load_balancers`.